# How to add a pdf to smtp email in power automate

Tags: power-automate

I would like to send an email with a PDF attachment from a SharePoint folder using the SMTP module in Power Automate.

For this, i retrieve the content of the file from sharepoint

[image]

Then, i put this content in the "ContentData" field of the SMTP module

[image]

By default the module adds a base64 converter which makes the pdf corrupted when i try to open it

[image]

By removing the base64, i can open the pdf but it displays a blank page

Any help is welcome

I've already searched all the forums to find a solution but couldn't find one

Comment: email attachments are always base64 encoded. Perhaps it is corrupted for a different reason.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey i think it's that because without the base64 i have a blank PDF and not a corrupted file.
Also when i create a new file in sharepoint with the content i retrieve it works